# Why was my question closed, and how can I have it reopened?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions

I'm a newcomer here in Stack Exchange. I've posted 3 questions and 2 of them are closed for being off-topic/not for this site / closed as not a real question.

Here is [a link to my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796265/how-to-translate-this-c-code-to-python/15796449) (which has since been deleted, so 10k+ only). Why was this closed even though I don't have my answers yet? And what can I do to have this question reopened?

Comment: Did you read any of the comments on your question? What did you do to address the community's queries? (thank you BTW for coming to meta; I hope you get sufficient help here to explain what's happening).

Comment: I am not unsympathetic to your frustration, but if you read through the site's FAQ, you will see that this type of question is not well suited for this site.  What IS well suited is a question that demonstrates what you've already tried (for example, some attempted Python code) and what specifically has not worked. P.S. I am NOT voting you down.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask. Especially the section on doing your homework.

Comment: @JeffWolski , tnq for you answer, this is what the new users want

Comment: @Sirajul_Islam  You are welcome.  Don't give up.  I think you'll find that if your questions fit the format and SHOW the effort that you're putting in, you will likely find good answers.

Comment: @JackManey If only project management was that easy.  Alas, it is [often] not.

Comment: @Servy - Regardless, we are not the OP's personal code monkeys.

Comment: @JackManey I know, I was just having some fun with you.

Answer (score 18):

> why?

Your questions were closed because they met the criteria for when a question should be closed for that particular reason, as is indicated by the detailed text explaining the closure.

At a higher level, answering the question of why SO closes questions in general is that in order to have very high quality answers (which is a stated goal of the site) you need high quality questions and lots of experts.  Low quality questions both drive away experts, and result in lower quality answers, so the site has created many guidelines for determining when questions should be closed.

> I haven't got my answers yet

That's kinda the point.  The questions were of such low quality that we feel they *shouldn't* be answered, as it would be harmful to the site to leave your question open.

> why the mods are so unfair

First, it wasn't a mod closing any of your questions, it was simply members of the community.  5 community members having at least 3,000 reputation voted to close your questions.  They were also not unfair; they were conforming to a set of guidelines defined in the FAQ to determine what types of questions should be closed.

> to new users?

It has nothing to do with you being new; it has everything to do with the quality of the question.  New users can (and do) as high quality questions that get upvotes, answers, and stay open, and likewise users who have been around for a while can and do ask low quality questions that get downvotes and close votes.

> How can I make the question reopened ?

By reading through the guidelines in the FAQ for what is and is not acceptable, removing content that shouldn't be there, generally improving the quality of the questions, and ensuring that they no longer meet the criteria for being closed.

To be a bit more specific to your questions:

For your [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523266/how-to-develop-better-algorithm):

It's really hard to understand what you're asking.  I've read through it several times and I just can't get a good grasp of what you're really asking for, or what you're expecting out of an answer.  While often I'll assume that even though I don't get it someone else might, this is so difficult to digest that I can completely understand closing it, at least until you can take some time to really figure out what you want to ask, and perhaps spend some time improving how you explain the question to others.

Another issue with the question, from what I can gather of what it's asking, is that it's very subjective.  You're not asking a *practical, solvable* programming problem, you're asking a question that has no right or wrong answer.  Most of these aren't a good fit for the site.  Some are on topic for other sites, such as programmers, but this question would most likely need some work before it would be on topic on *any* Stack Exchange site.

For your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796265/how-would-this-c-code-be-translated-to-python):

The main problem here is that you're just asking us to do your work for you.  There is no demonstration that you've tried to solve the problem yourself, or even spent any time on it at all. It would benefit a lot from spending some time trying to solve the problem (if you haven't already) and then explaining what you've tried so far in the post, along with what *specific* problems you're having with your attempted solution.  The question then morphs from "translate this for me" into something much more specific, such as "why does executing XYZ result in Foo instead of Bar?" which is a much better question.

Making such a change also makes the question much less localized.  As it is, the question is really only useful to you, and nobody else.  Such questions aren't appropriate for SO.  By explaining the problem you're having with your solution you add the possibility for someone else to have the same problem with a different bit of code, thus helping answers to your question help others, which is the primary purpose of the site.

Comment: Apologies for partly destroying the line of your answer. I thought it best to make the question constructive instead of a downvote magnet.

Comment: @Bart Completely understandable.

Comment: Answers to bad questions do NOT harm the site.  All good answers help.

Comment: @LanceRoberts Leaving very poor quality questions opened *so that they can be answered* harms the site.  Once they have already been answered those answers *sometimes* harm the site (think debates around not constructive questions) but aren't often harmful.  This is why answers to closed questions aren't (usually) deleted, and you can still vote on and get rep for them.

Answer (score 3):

Since each post is handled in isolation, you will need to dig into each single post to understand the reasons why it alone was closed.

You should try to self-educate yourself by spending about 30 minutes reading all you can about the reason it was closed, searching here for an answer, asking a co-worker or friend to assist you in understanding why the site is closing your posts.  <sub>Heck, This question itself is likely to get closed as a duplicate as there should be dozens of similar questions asking why other posts are closed.</sub>

Read up, try to edit the closed posts and ask for help as a last resort by flagging a moderator to look. Flag once and be patient - it might take up to a day to get a response and you might not get any assistance if the moderator is busy otherwise.

Since there are currently over 700 questions here tagged with [tag:closed-questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/closed-questions) - hopefully several others assist you in knowing you are not alone and you can figure this out if you care to.

- Good Luck and go slowly.
- Read the [about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and [guide on how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) is the best advice I can give.

Comment: While maybe good advice I fail to see how this helps the OP to understand why their questions were closed.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I'm intentionally not doing the work for the OP and parsing their closed questions for them. I am giving them the benefit of the doubt that they actually want to learn how the site works and pointing out starting points. I'm here to point the way to fishing lessons, not catch a specific fish. YMMV.

Comment: By example is a good teaching method though. The OP has come to meta specifically to find out why their questions are being closed (don't forget this is MSO as well as MSE). As they've come here we should be doing what we can to save them. Not always possible, I know, but a post here after 3 questions is a great sign that they want to engage with the rest of the community. A bunch of platitudes, however correct, doesn't address the salient point; what exactly went wrong this time.

Comment: I get your point - they came and asked about one question. I chose to focus on a larger problem. It's clearly not the direct answer, but it's what I wanted to contribute at the moment.

Answer (score -8):

**People can be a little silly sometimes on closing basic questions.**

Having said that, I hope you pay attention to the different edits done, and the advice given in the comments there and here to make your future questions better.  The way the world works is that appearance is important, so you want to put a lot of work in making your post look good, so it won't attract negativity from those who will judge your post that way.  Part of making your post look good is to show what effort you've put in, so they don't feel like they're helping someone too lazy to do any research themselves.

Comment: I don't think either of the questions that were closed were closed because they were basic.  In fact the only question of his that is open is much more basic than the other two.  Both questions were appropriately closed for reasons entirely unrelated to the level of skill needed to solve them.

Comment: We know you hate seeing closed questions, but people aren't being silly closing basic questions.  Stack Overflow isn't for converting your code to another language when you haven't shown any effort; closing NaRQ is justified.

Comment: Haha, I've got to give it to you, you stand by what you say. That edit amuses me more than it perhaps should have. :)

Comment: @BlahBlahGrabblesnackers, no, code translation questions are fine.  We just don't want to do all the work for them necessarily.

Comment: if it is a real question then it's too localised (no one is going to be translating that exact code-chunk). Code translations about some specific translation problem can be useful, but not just "translate it all plz".

Comment: @hayden, yeh, he should have distilled it down to one statement and asked for the Python equivalent.