# Why is a question about measuring cat feces an audit for close votes?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, vote-to-close, specific-question, review-audits

[Counting column data in a matrix with resets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20496904/r-counting-column-data-in-a-matrix-with-resets) starts off with:

> I'm gathering data on how much my cats poop into a matrix:

Most shockingly, this line says:

> The **cumsum** function does something similar, but that's a primitive so I can't modify it to suit my dirty, dirty needs.

And in the closing

> I have a lot of cats, and I've recorded years worth of poop data.

Could someone please explain why this question is allowed in its current form on Stack Overflow? I think this is a great question for Code Golf.

Does anyone really think this user collects a record of their cats' waste?

But the problem that the question exists isn't my main concern. My main concern is that this is an audit question for close votes. I failed it for clicking close. I find that it should be closed under "offensive".

Comment: Who are we to judge people on their cat poop data collection?

Comment: It's a real question, with some humor thrown in. What exactly do you think is wrong with the question itself?

Comment: [`cumsum()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/cumsum.html) is an actual function in R. It means "cumulative sum". Are you shocked and offended by questions about [`touch`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?touch), [`finger`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?finger), and [`mount`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?mount+8), too?

Comment: First vote to close cast, thanks for bringing it to our attention.

Comment: @LanceRoberts What, exactly, is close-worthy there?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Like I said in my post. I don't really personally care if the question exists, but it should definitley not be an audit question. I think it belongs on CODE-Golf, where this sort of thing is more approved of. But I'm still kinda new, so if someone could answer how I should handle these types of things and why, I'd love to have that info.

Comment: I don't think it will be an audit anymore, it has 2 downvotes and so I think that will kick it out of the queue. Is that right, @animuson?

Comment: @hichris123 I don't know how audits are chosen.

Comment: I won't lie , I find the post does have really good sense of humor.. but when I'm in "moderator mode" , I act more like a strict librarian!

Comment: scatological references aside, this audit is a gas

Comment: Interestingly, this post has been used for audits 12 times, and only 2 people have failed.

Comment: @animuson Thanks for the statistics, that makes me feel special.

Comment: Did this post actually offend you personally? Or you just thought someone somewhere might be offended?

Comment: @MartinSmith I'm not offended, I just think it was a really great sort of trollish post that would be great on code-golf. I haven't ran into a question like that on SO before, so I thought it should be closed. And was shocked to find out it was an audit, that's why I posted here. The shock is gone though, don't worry.

Comment: @AlienArrays - Probably someone, somewhere, is actually doing genuine research on this very topic. Wouldn't be surprised to see [an IgNobel prize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ig_Nobel_Prize_winners) to join such classics as "The Constipated Serviceman: Prevalence Among Deployed US Troops" or "Pressures Produced When Penguins Poo—Calculations on Avian Defecation"

Comment: @MartinSmith I'm so angry at myself for not studying medicine or biology right now. Would love to do either one as a thesis

Comment: @Pëkka - As a faeces? Though strangely the penguin one came under Physics (fluid dynamics)

Comment: @MartinSmith there is room for an interdisciplinary approach, then! Even better.

Comment: It's amazing to me, @Lance, how you [defend everyone's](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175033/159251) right [to answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209031/159251) and [insist on correctness in close votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202868/) but jump right on this question as "trolling" because it contains something you apparently consider a dirty word.

Comment: It's amazing to me @Josh, that you think SO should be the sewer of the Internet.  There are plenty of filthy sites out there, why do you insist that this site be one also.

Comment: Real poop goes into the sewer, @Lance; the word is just a name for it, and using it doesn't hurt anyone. **Edit it** if you have another name you prefer _that_ strongly. I think 100% of the English speakers I know would put "poop" in the top five mildest, least-offensive terms for that substance. The question could be changed to replace "makes poopies" with "eats tuna fish" without altering the technical issue one iota.

Comment: I wonder if they were successful in making their algorithm... could have implications for the kitty litter industry!

Comment: I really don't understand the concept... is poop profanity? Kitty poop, for potato sake! A web hit of the first kind.

Comment: ...and Lance apparently also thinks a question [whose highest-voted answer is a joke about pedophilia](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/614232/revisions) is so important -- and definitely _not_ at all dirty or offensive -- that [it needs to be undeleted three years later](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/140376/revisions).

Comment: "you think SO should be the sewer of the Internet" -- Of course Josh doesn't think that. And I don't think SO should be a manifestation of one person's extremely neurotic attitudes toward excrement.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't understand what's wrong with this as an audit. It's a highly-upvoted, clear question with (as far as I can see) a few solid answers. There's no "offensive" close reason. You're thinking of the "edit" button.

If you ignore the "p**p" for a moment<sup>*</sup>, the question **clearly** describes a **specific coding** problem, **demonstrates understanding** of the domain, and admits a **bounded answer**. No close reason applies here; the question should remain open.

---

<sup>*</sup>And take a second to realize that `cumsum()` is [a function in R for "cumulative sum"](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/cumsum.html).

Comment: +1 Changing "cat poops" to "defecates", "creates feces", or something more scientific would be fine

Comment: Really? "poop" is pretty mild where I come from. That's what kids in kindergarten call it.

Comment: Cf. ["Everybody Poops"](http://www.amazon.com/Everyone-Poops-Body-Science-Series/dp/192913214X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1388959027&sr=8-1&keywords=everybody+poops), recommended for ages 2 and up.

Answer (score 6):

I guess "poop" is technically slang but I can't imagine a proficient speaker of English not knowing it. And it's certainly more likely they would know it than "feces" or even something like "carburetor," which would be a valid domain-specific term. 4 year olds learn the word and that's what they call it.

And you go with "offensive"? What exactly about cats pooping and doing statistics on it is offensive?

If it's not offensive, then...  what are you closing it for? It just felt somehow *wrong* to have the word "poop" in it? You can't just make up close reasons. That's one things audits are for, to make sure you're not doing that.

Comment: Gah! Would you _please_ use a couple of asteri**s in the "carb"-word?!

Comment: @JoshCaswell maybe on the part I'm not sure if I spelled right.

Comment: @AlienArrays think you're reading into it there. Don't think there's any way the OP could have actually used the cumsum function while making it sound less like a pun on the slangier parts. Pretty clear "dirty, dirty needs" is referring to cat poop. No reference to bestiality in the post.

Comment: @AlienArrays FTR if I actually saw a "cum" joke on SO, I would either edit or flag depending on whether it sounded lighthearted (but inappropriate) or troll-ish in my judgment. In that case I would say it would make a bad audit, since our audits don't really test for "did you edit or flag instead of close or leave alone".